# drupal Cross Site Scripting (Reflected)

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, owasp

Site has ran in the OWASP ZAP Testing Tool, Getting thowing the cross site scripting error.
please share some remediation Technique to fix XSS Problem.

URL: example.com/sites/javascript:alert(1);/modules/lightbox2/js
Parameter: all

This tool does not provided the following information
 1. in which place / which file hacking may occur.

Please advise to how to fix the XSS problem

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the injection might be falling inside of a link href, iframe src, or some other place that handles URL redirection. It is really not possible to tell without seeing where the reflection is in the source or generated source (DOM) of the page.

A generic suggestion would be to have the application remove javascript: (and the various ways of encoding it such as URL, HTML, etc) from user input.

Comment: i dont know, where this word " javascript:alert(1); " exist in the module. becauase module which i uploaded are the third party contri modules.

Comment: the javascript:alert(1) is being injected via the URL and being reflected into the source or DOM of the page and is not part of the module. More than likely that part of the URL, in what looks like a restFUL URI, is being placed in something like    <a href="javascript:alert(1);">LINK</a>  or     <iframe src=javascript:alert(1)></iframe>.     Tried to put those in code blocks but for some reason I can never format these responses and hitting enter submits the response instead of going down a line.